# Ruby Bunny exchange wait_for_confirm or die

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

What would be the best way to incorporate something similar to the RabbitMQ `channel.waitForConfirmsOrDie()` method, while utilizing the Bunny gem for a publish confirmation?

Right now I am using:

```
if !@channel.using_publisher_confirmations?
    @channel.confirm_select
end

@channel.default_exchange.publish(args)

was_successful = @channel.wait_for_confirms()
```

But ideally, for the scenario I need, I would like to have a much shorter timeout on waiting for the confirmations. Right now, it seems as though there is a default timeout of roughly 15 seconds, but that is far too long to block the thread. If I don't receive confirmation within, say, three seconds, what I'd like to have happen is raise an exception/return false.

I saw there was a [`waitForConfirmsOrDie()`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v3.5.1/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-3.5.1/com/rabbitmq/client/Channel.html#waitForConfirmsOrDie()) in the RabbitMQ documentation, but Bunny does not have this as a method available.

Am I considering rewriting some methods for similar functionality. Has anyone come across something similar and found a good way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't wait for confirms synchronously. You should use a technique similar [to this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-seven-java.html) to keep track of outstanding confirms and handle them.